# references don't show up properly with use of some unusual *.cls

Tags: cross-referencing

```
\documentclass{imuwbth}
\begin{document}
\chapter{chapter1}
\begin{dfn}\label{WP}
 \emph{WP} is called something when it meets:
  \begin{equation}\label{W0}\tag{W0}
            0=0
  \end{equation}
  \begin{equation}\label{W1}\tag{W1}
            1=1
  \end{equation}
  \begin{equation}\label{W2}\tag{W2}
            2=2
  \end{equation}
  \begin{equation}\label{W3}\tag{W3}
            3=3     
  \end{equation}.
\end{dfn}
\chapter{chapter2}
\begin{dfn}
 if (\ref{W0}), (\ref{W1}), (\ref{W3}) from dfn of (\ref{WP}) WP (page \pageref{WP})     and:
  \begin{equation}\label{W2a}\tag{W2a}
    5=5
  \end{equation}
  \begin{equation}\label{W2b}\tag{W2b}
    6=6
  \end{equation}
  \begin{equation}\label{W2c}\tag{W2c}
    7=7
  \end{equation}
 Then something.
\end{dfn}
\end{document}
```

this 'imuwbth' thing could be downloaded from here https://www.dropbox.com/s/ju72mhb64j9p998/imuwbth.cls

I cannot edit that, and have to use it. But it makes references just wrong. Image shows the problem. I have this:

[image]

Any solutions?

Comment: While you "cannot edit `imuwbth.cls`", are redefinitions to accommodate your request fine?

Comment: If I've understood right, I think that answer is yes. As long as redefinitions are only in the output tex file. But wouldn't they conflict with cls file? However it is no longer needed, because solution proposed by @egreg worked just fine. Anyway thanks for your desire to help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The class redefines `equation` so that each `\label` command shows the key in the margin. This is made in such a way that it overrides the adjustments already done by `amsmath`. If you use `gather` (which you should, for multiline displays), the references will be correct.

In my opinion the class does too much work for something that could simply be achieved by loading `showkeys`. That redefinition of `equation` is plainly wrong.